# How to rewrite this sentence to relate the participle phrase to the word it modifies?

Tags: sentence-construction, participle-phrases

“Looking down from the summit” is a participle phrase, but in this sentence it is modifying “Stacy’s friends’ faces” instead of “Stacy”. So, how to rewrite this sentence to relate the participle phrase to the subject ‘Stacy’

Looking down from the summit, Stacy's friends' faces were blurry as they smiled up at her.

Comment: A dangling participle, by definition, has no subject to refer to. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Who do you want to look down from the summit, Stacy or the friends? At the moment the *author* is looking down from the summit and observing the friends smiling up at Stacy. Perhaps you could explain in a longer paragraph exactly what the situation is?

Comment: Looking down from the summit, Stacy saw her friends' blurry faces smiling up at her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than interpreting the sentence as you've written it, I believe what you're asking for is how it *should* be written if you want *looking down from the summit* to indicate something that Stacy is doing.

A possible version of the sentence is this:

> Looking down from the summit, Stacy saw her friends' faces as a blur when they smiled up at her.

Note that I used *as a blur* because it's not literally true that her friends' faces *were* blurry, just that they *appeared* that way. (I'm being precise, in order to match the precision of the rest of the sentence.)

---

The essential component is this:

> Doing X, Y . . .

You need to drop the use of the possessive *Stacy's* and use the just *Stacy*. Then finish the sentence in a different way. (In my example revision, I used *her friends'*.)

Answer (score 0):

**Looking down from the summit** is not modifying "Stacy's friends faces".  It is a free-standing clause that can be understood as a kind of *deixis*, presenting a point-of-view.

From a position on the summit looking down, those faces far below appeared blurry.